# Haskell Servant: GET Requests with arbitrary request data

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework, servant

I'm serving an API using Servant, all managed by Snap. In Servant, it's easy to include an arbitrary data type as part of a POST request, assuming it has a `FromJSON` instance. For instance, I might have the following endpoint:

```
ReqBody '[JSON] RequestData :> Post '[JSON] [ResponseData]
```

How do I do the same for GET requests? From what I understand, I'd need to use the Query Parameters, but my request data consists of complex datatypes (lists, nested dictionaries) that don't seem to be readable easily, e.g. `QueryParam "vals" [Int] :> Post '[JSON] [Int]` results in the error `No instance for (FromHttpApiData [Int])`

A workaround would be to use POST requests, which have easily readable request bodies. However, this would clash with my caching scheme in Nginx, since responses to POST requests aren't that easily cachable. Even if I can cache them, I don't want to cache all post requests, so it'd be a messy approach.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you don't mind orphan instances, why not just define an instance yourself for `(FromHttpApiData a) => FromHttpApiData [a]`

Comment: @Probie thanks, that's a clean approach for a single request type. However, I have many request types. It feels odd that I need to write a `FromHttpApiData` instance for each data type `RequestData1, RequestData2,...`, all of which can be complex. Since a POST request body can be parsed automatically, it seems like I should be able to re-use the code used there, or is there a technical limitation that prevents doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution if you want the same level of automatic derivation as for JSON post bodies is to just send the query params as JSON

```
import Data.Aeson
import Servant.API
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Text.Encoding
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS

newtype JSONEncoded a = JSONEncoded { unJSONEncoded :: a }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance (FromJSON a) => FromHttpApiData (JSONEncoded a) where
  parseQueryParam x = case eitherDecode $ LBS.fromStrict $ encodeUtf8 x of
    Left err -> Left (T.pack err)
    Right val -> Right (JSONEncoded val)

instance (ToJSON a) => ToHttpApiData (JSONEncoded a) where
  toQueryParam (JSONEncoded x) = decodeUtf8 $ LBS.toStrict $ encode x
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Since this approach returns a `Maybe (JSONEncoded a))`, I added a helper of type `maybeHandler :: HasDefault d => (a -> Handler b Service d) -> Maybe (JSONEncoded a) -> Handler b Service d` so I can continue using my existing API, which is defined through functions of type `a -> Handler b Service d`. Whenever the JSON could not be parsed, the default value for `d` is returned.

Comment: What happens if my query parameters contain a large list? Would there be any concerns about a URL that balloons to thousands of characters?